# ng-show/ng-hide not behaving as expected

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to show a spinner while something is loading, so I have:

```
<small-spinner class="spinner fa-spin" ng-show="suggestion.voting"></small-spinner>
<i class="fa fa-arrow-up" ng-hide="suggestion.voting"></i>
```

And $scope.suggestion.voting is set in the controller. However, when `suggestion.voting` is set to `0` the spinner remains for a few seconds longer before disappearing. How could this be so?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Here's the fix: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8224#issuecomment-50413972